# How can I enable composition modes using QPainter.CompositionMode with QGraphicsItem in a painting app in Qt5?

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, qt5, pyside6

QGraphicsItem with QPainter.CompositionMode

I'm trying to create a painting app in Qt5 (c++ or python), and I need to use **QPainter.CompositionMode** and **QGraphicsItem** together. Out of the box, QGraphicsScene can handle the layering, grouping, moving, painting, rotating, etc, but not composition modes (add, subtract, overlay, multiply, etc) that are needed to make this app. I can't figure out how to enable composition modes in the QGraphicsScene space. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

ps. I've rolled my own QPixmap list renderer WITH composition modes, but it doesn't play well QGraphicsScene and is ultimately an anti-pattern.

Comment: It seems that you want to set the composition mode on a per item basis, so you just set it in the override of the `paint()` method of items.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?